# Arranging objects in a circle

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

**Question**

Suppose you have $4$ sets of $5$ blocks. Each set consists of a triangle, a square, a parallelogram and $2$ identical pentagons of the same colour. Find the number of ways you can arrange all of the blocks in a circle, with all the pentagons together and no two triangles adjacent.

**My solution**

1. Arrange those blocks which have no restrictions first (i.e. the squares and parallelograms), giving us $$(8 - 1)!.$$
2. Next, slot in the triangles and arrange them. We have $8$ spots in the circle to choose from, giving us $$\binom 8 4 4!.$$
3. Now, treat all of the pentagons as one set and slot the entire set of pentagons into the circle. We have $12$ spots in the circle to choose from, giving us $$\binom {12} 1.$$
4. Lastly, we need to arrange the pentagons and recalling that we actually only have 4 distinct sets of pentagons, so we have $$\frac {8!} {2!2!2!2!}.$$

This works out to be $$(8 - 1)!\binom 8 4 4! \binom {12} 1 \frac {8!} {2!2!2!2!} \approx 2.56 \times 10^{11}.$$

**The answer**

1. Arrange those blocks which have no restrictions first (i.e. the squares and parallelograms), giving us $$(8 - 1)!.$$
2. Next, treat all of the pentagons as one set and slot the entire set of pentagons into the circle. We have $8$ spots in the circle to choose from, giving us $$\binom 8 1.$$
3. Now, we need to arrange the pentagons and recalling that we actually only have 4 distinct sets of pentagons, so we have $$\frac {8!} {2!2!2!2!}.$$
4. Lastly, slot in the triangles and arrange them. We have $9$ spots in the circle to choose from, giving us $$\binom 9 4 4!.$$

This works out to be $$(8 - 1)!\binom 8 1 \frac {8!} {2!2!2!2!} \binom 9 4 4! \approx 3.07 \times 10^{11}.$$

---

I was going through this question with a student of mine today and I was not able to explain to him why my solution does not give the correct answer. In particular, if we compare my solution to the answer, they simply slotted the pentagons before slotting the triangles, while I had slotted the triangles before slotting the pentagons. Both methods (mine and the answer) seem perfectly logical to me, so I cannot, for the life of me, wrap my head around why my solution is incorrect. Any intuitive explanations will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: The colors don't matter ?

Comment: @trueblueanil Ah yes... the colours were for a different part of the question. The colours are not relevant here. I will edit it out!

Comment: We can have two triangles adjacent in step two (example: ATTATATAAAAA) and then insert 8 pentagons between them in step three (example: ATPPPPPPPPTATATAAAAA) so in your solution you are missing out some cases.

Comment: @Asher2211 How can we have two triangles adjacent in my second step? I specifically did $\binom 8 4$, meaning I am choosing 4 distinct spots in the circle to fit my triangles right? In particular, the spots I can choose from, which I label as H, are HAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA (no pun intended) right? Comparing my solution to the answer, it does indeed seem that I am missing some cases, but I do not think it is because of the adjacency of my triangles (I think I have already accounted for that).

Comment: You must **push in** the triangles in the gaps (not disturbing the pentagon block) after placing all the others

Comment: It is not that they are adjacent, you haven't given *all possible liberty* to be non-adjacent.

Comment: @EthanMark What I mean is that if you slot the way you did in the second step then you won't have the complete set of combinations. The example I gave before is a valid arrangement which cannot be obtained from your method.

Comment: @Asher2211 Oh... you are not telling me that my second step has adjacent triangles. Instead, you are trying to tell me the opposite... that my second step precisely has not accounted for the possibility of adjacent triangles such that they become non-adjacent after placing the pentagons. Very brilliant thinking indeed. Totally missed this case out. Thank you for the short discussion. Would you mind putting consolidating your comments into an answer so I can accept it and close this question?

Comment: Btw, you are permitted to answer your own question.

Comment: @trueblueanil Yes, I know that, but then I would be stealing the credit from both of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first solution you didn't account for the possibility of adjacent triangles which become non-adjacent after placing the pentagons.

For example a combination like ATPPPPPPPPTATATAAAAA (Where A$\to$squares/parallelograms, T$\to$ triangles,P$\to$pentagons) cannot be obtained from the first solution but it can be obtained from the second solution.